# How to I set a string variable that has CR\LF's into a Winform textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms textbox set to AcceptReturns = true, Scrollbars = vertical, Multiline = true.
I construct a string called note by looping thru a datatable, putting the value into note with: note = note plus a "\n\n".
When I view the string with the text visualizer, it shows the CR\LF's correctly but after the command: remarks.text = note, the textbox DOES NOT have the CR\LF's. 
How do I get the CR\LF's to be respected?

```
                int x = 0;
                string note = "";
                command = null;
                DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();
                foreach (string rcd in app.feecd) // app.feecd is an array established earlier in code
                {
                    command = GetConnectedClass.newsqlconnection("SELECT NoteDesc from dbo.inspnote where NoteCode = @selcode");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selcode", rcd);
                    dtnew.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                    note = note + dtnew.Rows[x].Field<string>("NoteDesc") + "\n\n";
                    command = null;
                    x = x + 1;
                }

                if (remarks.Text == "")
                { remarks.Text = note; } // note has CR\LF but remarks.Text NO CR\LF ????
                else { remarks.Text = remarks.Text + "\n\n" + note; }
```

Comment: Always use `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: Whenever submitting a question on SO please use the simplest minimal example that would describe the issue you are having--something the community can easily duplicate in our own environments. The code segment you have provided may have issues, which we cannot necessarily duplicate. Please read: [mcve]

Comment: As an afterthought. I did Clipboard.SetText(note); and pasted into Notepad. It was correct.

Comment: I changed the \n to \r\n and it now works...

Comment: And why not take the advice of @AlexanderPetrov and use the platform independent `Environment.NewLine`? [Environment.NewLine Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=netcore-3.1) :: "A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms."